Ubuntu 24.04.1 will not boot properly
I started using my new laptop, Acer Aspire 5, two days ago. It came with Windows 11 preinstalled. I installed Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1 from the Live CD after partitioning the hard drive with Gparted.
The issue I am facing is that nothing happens when I turn on my laptop and select Ubuntu from the Grub menu. The screen turns gray and it stays like that. I am then forced to power down the computer and turn it on again. After I do that, everything works normally. I do not know why.
I am afraid that this might create issues with the hard drive in the long run, and I sincerely want to avoid that.
I will appreciate all the help I can get to fix this issue.
PS: It seems that sometimes this issue also occurs when I reboot after a software update. I am puzzled. I would expect this behaviour from an old laptop, not a new one.
PPS: I tried using the Live CD but with Ubuntu 18.04 (it took me half an hour just to load 24.04 from the CD) to run fsck but the computer froze saying that it could not find a bootable disk.
